# How can I make a multiple bar chart in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling a bit with ggplot2 and hoping to learn by example a bit more.

I have a lot of data that looks like like the thing this generates:

```
data.frame(version=c('v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2'),
           platform=c('linux', 'linux', 'mac', 'mac',
                      'linux', 'linux', 'mac', 'mac'),
           type=c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'),
           count=floor(runif(8, 0, 10000)))
```

I got regular `barplot` to draw me a stacked bar chart of type for a given OS (by slicing it out with `cast`, but I've not quite got what I want with ggplot2 yet.

I can manage to plot a single platform by doing something like this (assuming the above is saved as `sample`):

```
qplot(version, a, data=cast(sample[sample$platform=='linux',],
                            version ~ type, value="count"),
      geom='bar')
```

Ideally, I'd like that stacked by type (explicitly `a` in this example -- there are only two types) and then have one per platform appear side-by-side on the same chart grouped by version.

That is, for every version, I'd like three bars (one for each platform) with two stacks each (by type).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one option:

```
dat <- data.frame(version=c('v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2', 'v2'),
           platform=c('linux', 'linux', 'mac', 'mac',
                      'linux', 'linux', 'mac', 'mac'),
           type=c('a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'),
           count=floor(runif(8, 0, 10000)))


ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = platform, y = count)) + 
    facet_wrap(~version) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill = type))
```

which produces something like this:

[image]

Your example data only had two platforms, so maybe that was just a typo since you referenced three.

Comment: Oh sorry about that.  I do have three in my real data, but my sample only had two.  Got tiring to type all of the combinations.  :)  This looks pretty good.  I think it may be easier to understand than exactly what I asked for.

Comment: @Dustin No problem. [This](http://learnr.wordpress.com/) blog has lots of good ggplot2 examples, as does Hadley's [site](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) but his book is by far the best reference.